# React-Redux mapDispatchToProps not receiving mapStateToProps

Tags: redux, react-redux

In my `mapStateToProps` function I set `idToken` and `accessToken` to values stored in state.  This works, as I've been able to reference these values from the component.  In `mapDispatchToProps` I try to use these props as arguments in my action.  However, `ownProps` is an empty object.  Why doesn't it have `idToken` and `accessToken`?

container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleAddQuestionModal, fetchFriends } from '../actions'
import AddQuestionButtonComponent from '../components/AddQuestionButton'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  auth = state.auth
  return {
    idToken: auth.token.idToken,
    accessToken: auth.profile.identities[0].accessToken,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    didPress: (idToken, accessToken) => {
      dispatch(toggleAddQuestionModal(true))
      dispatch(fetchFriends(ownProps.idToken, ownProps.accessToken))
    }
  }
}

AddQuestionButton = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AddQuestionButtonComponent)

export default AddQuestionButton
```

component:

```
'use strict';

import React, {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  PropTypes,
} from 'react-native'

import styles from './styles'

const AddQuestionButton = ({ didPress, idToken, accessToken }) => (
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.actionButton} onPress={didPress(idToken, accessToken)}>
    <Text style={styles.actionButtonText}>+</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
)
AddQuestionButton.propTypes = {
  idToken: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  accessToken: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  didPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default AddQuestionButton
```

Why can't I access `idToken` and `accessToken` from `ownProps`?  If this in an incorrect pattern, how should `idToken` and `accessToken` be accessed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, the `ownProps` parameter refers to props the component receives via attributes, for example:

`<AddQuestionButton isVisible={ true } />`

The `isVisible` attribute will be passed as `ownProps`. In this way, you can have a component that receives some props from redux, and some props from attributes.

The [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method itself have a third parameter called `mergeProps`:

> [mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps): props] (Function):
>   If specified, it is passed the result of mapStateToProps(),
>   mapDispatchToProps(), and the parent props. The plain object you
>   return from it will be passed as props to the wrapped component. You
>   may specify this function to select a slice of the state based on
>   props, or to bind action creators to a particular variable from props.
>   If you omit it, Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps)
>   is used by default.

In the merge props, you actually get to combine all props together, as you can see in this answer by Dan Abramov to this [issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/237):

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    isFollowing: state.postsFollowing[ownProps.id]
  };
}

function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
  const { isFollowing } = stateProps;
  const { dispatch } = dispatchProps;
  const { id } = ownProps;

  const toggle = isFollowing ?
    unfollowPostActionCreator :
    followPostActionCreator;

  return {
    ...stateProps,
    ...ownProps,
    toggleFollow: () => dispatch(toggle(id)))
  };
}

ToggleFollowButton = connect({
  mapStateToProps,
  null, // passing null instead of mapDispatchToProps will return an object with the dispatch method
  mergeProps
})(ToggleFollowButton)
```